# regex for access log in Hive RegexSerDe

Tags: regex, hive

I'm very new in developing regular expressions. Can any one help me to build a common regular expression for the following two strings.

1. **offset=0**&**fileGuid=1014fc48-6eb3-4fff-8242-96f5a496b0ee**
2. file=Arnold+P+Gleit+Contract+Information.pdf&param=CommandType=1.1.2.1~ProjectID=13979~FolderID=1344972~UserID=13395&**fileGuid=51c01e15-ac3c-4d2d-bdc9-4e63251a0364**&location=CommandType=1.1.2.1~ProjectID=13979~FolderID=1344972~UserID=13395&size=28357151&title=&desc=&searchtags=&OnDuplicateAction=2&**offset=1703936**&first=True&last=False

My intention is to get the value of "**offset**" and "**fileGuid**" and load the data into a Hive table.
I tried with the regular expression --

```
"input.regex" = "offset=([0-9]+).*\\&fileGuid=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
```

This will work for the first string but will fail for the 2nd string.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try the [following](http://regex101.com/r/uB9rZ7) or [this](http://regex101.com/r/pW7wH7) if your regex flavor supports named groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick: `/offset=([^&$]+)|fileGuid=([^&$]+)/`

Basically it matches `offset=<string to next & or end of line>` or `fileGuid=<string to next & or end of line>`

Example: http://regexr.com?34t57

It might also be convenient to add the offset/fileGuid strings to your matches so its easier to see which is which, to do that make it like `(offset)=([^&$]+)|(fileGuid)=([^&$]+)`.

Comment: Hi Damien,

Thanks for your quick reply.

I tried with **"input.regex" = "/offset=([^&$]+)|fileGuid=([^&$]+)/"** but the result was NULL for both the lines. Then I tried with

**"input.regex" = "offset=([^&$]+).*fileGuid=([^&$]+)|.*fileGuid=([^&$]+).*offset=([^&$]+).*"**

The result was

0 1014fc48-6eb3-4fff-8242-96f5a496b0ee
NULL NULL

It processed the first line perfectly but missed the 2nd line. Please guide me if I'm missing anything.


Thanks & Regards

Comment: I dont know what is going wrong. I don't know the Hive environment. It's working in the example I provided. So the regex seems to be correct..